# GlassFish V3 Cluster + TimesTen strange behavior

Tags: java, glassfish-3, timesten

i have a very strange problem with GlassFish V3 + TimesTen.
My configuration is:

1. GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
2. TimesTen Release 11.2.2.2.0
3. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM      (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode).
4. Linux 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
5. Two machine with same hadrware (second server is clone of the first one).

GlassFish, TimesTen, Java and Linux are same on the both servers.

I have GlassFish DAS on the server one. Successfully created Node-agent with one instance (on the localhost), deployed my application, which communicate with TimesTen Database, configure JVM Options in GlassFish and my application works perfect. I'd tested it with Soap UI and have correct response.

But when I created node + instance on a remote server two, application wont work on this machine. Configuration of the glassfish instance are the same, because instances are in the same cluster.

I have these errors in server.log:

> *Connection could not be allocated because: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttJdbc.so:
>   libtten.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

Permissions on the both files:

```
-rwxr-x---. 1 esb esb 444K Dec 23  2011 /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttJdbc.so 

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 esb esb 18M Apr 10  2012 /opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libtten.so
```

Env. variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH on the both machines are the same:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib
```

Libs in instances root folders are the same on both servers. I'd try to add JVM Option:

```
-Djava.library.path=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib
```

but it's take no effect, error in server.log are the same. 
How else I can fix this?

PS: Just now tried this: installed same glassfish on the second machine, copyed libs in the domain1/libs directory, configure JDBC Resource like on the server one, deployed my app and its work perfect! 
But its wont work with cluster configuration...

PPS: on the glassfish v 2.1.1 everything works fine. I have 7 instances on 4 servers with same app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it out.
Write simpe script like this:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib"
/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-local-instance --user admin --passwordfile /glassfish3/passwd --node YOURNODE --sync normal YOURINSTANCE`

Then start instance with this script. 
And then my application works fine :)